# Installing python on CentOS

Tags: centos, python

I am unable to digest the fact that Linux CentOS requires users to do so much just for installing Python. It was so easy installing python on Ubuntu.

Also since CentOS comes with python2.5 it leads me to believe that it is not made for python specific usage.

But in case of centos i need to wget then tar then install. It does so much at back that I dont even know whats going wrong in it.

Is there a package installer for CentOS which can install python2.7, python 3.4 as easily as in ubuntu?

Comment: No version of CentOS comes with python 2.5.

Comment: Python is a core part of Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and thus a core part of CentOS. A lot of the Red Hat-specific parts of the OS is written in Python, as is the installer. The only tricky bit about using Python on RHEL type OSes is using a different version than it shipped with, since replacing such a core component has consequences. This is why the IUS repos mentioned in [jordanm's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216787/138) name the alternate Pythons differently.

Comment: @WarrenYoung this is no different from another distro such as `Ubuntu`, `Debian`. You can't change the *default* version and expect things to continue to work.

Comment: I just installed Python 3.4 on CentOs 7 with this tutorial: [Digital Ocean: Setup Python on CentOs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4). It has easy to follow instructions with helpful warnings and links to explanations of what's going on when you run the commands. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any luck through YUM command?

Below command can give you more information about python packages along with versions that are installed & available as updates.

```
yum list python --showduplicates
```

If you find any package with version that meets your need, then install it by:

```
yum install python-<version>
```

Comment: it only gives python 2.6.6 as available and installed

Comment: its a pain in the *** to install python on centos

Answer (score 7):

All versions of CentOS come with `python` pre-installed. Version 5 has python 2.4, 6 has 2.6, and 7 has 2.7. If you need python 2.7 on an old version of CentOS, you can use the [IUS repos](https://iuscommunity.org/pages/Repos.html).

To use the repo, you need to install the release RPM for your version of CentOS. For CentOS 6:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
```

Once the repo is setup, you can use `yum` to install the alternate versions of `python`:

```
yum install python27 python34
```

Note that this does not change the *default* version of `python`. It is an alternate installation, so you need to specify `python27` or `python34` to use them.

Comment: i need python 2.7 and python 3.4 on centOS 6

Comment: @mousecoder both are available in the IUS repo.

Comment: I see. Can you also tell me the how to use the IUS repo. basically commands to get IUS repo and use it to install python

Comment: @mousecoder updated

Comment: I am getting this error: `Retrieving https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UTsZzB: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 9cd4953f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
 epel-release = 6 is needed by ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos6.noarch`

Comment: @mousecoder updated again

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!! I was very scared in between. Now it seems to work very good!! :)

Comment: However, yum install python34 doesn't seem to be working. It says it isn't available.